# Copy multiple files from one folder to another

Tags: scala, file-io

I am trying to copy multiple files from one folder to another using the following code

```
val pathCorpus = Files.copy(
  Paths.get("src/main/resources/corpusDirectory/corpus.mallet"),
  Paths.get("src/main/resources/corpus.mallet"),
  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
)

val pathInferencer = Files.copy(
  Paths.get("src/main/resources/corpusDirectory/inferencer"),
  Paths.get("src/main/resources/inferencer"),
  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
)
```

As I need to copy two files, I am using `Files.copy` twice.
The code is working but I believe there should be better way to write the code, like copying files recursively.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use bash

```
import scala.sys.process.stringToProcess
val copyFiles: String = s"cp -R src/main/resources/corpusDirectory/ src/main/resources/".!!
```

And you can use bash cp: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/copy-command/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileUtils.copyDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)l)

```
val source = "C:/your/source";
val srcDir = new File(source);

val destination = "C:/your/destination";
val destDir = new File(destination);

    FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
```

Thanks,

Comment: i have tried copyDirectory but scala shows can not resolve copyDirectory. could you please suggest the name of import package as well

Answer (score 1):

[`better-files`](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#file-system-operations) supports recursively copying directories via `source.copyTo(destination)` syntax. Here is a working example

```
import better.files._

object Hello extends App {
  val source = file"/your/sourceDir"
  val destination = file"/your/destinationDir"
  source.copyTo(destination)
}
```

where we need the following dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "3.8.0"
```